# Cant install NVIDIA display drivers with thunderbolt connected Akitio Node eGPU on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS T2-linux Macbook Pro 16 inch Intel 2019 (dualboot)

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, gpu-driver, macbook-pro, thunderbolt

I have Ubuntu-22.04.3-LTS successfully installed on MacbookPro-16,1 based on the documentation available on T2linux page (https://wiki.t2linux.org/distributions/ubuntu/installation/). Display, Wifi, Bluetooth, Audio, Camera, Keyboard and Touchpad etc are all working for now.

In order to use this machine for data science work. I am connecting my Akitio Node eGPU box containing Nvidia 1080Ti via Thunderbolt

- System Info: Apple Inc. MacBookPro16,1 - NAVI14 (navi14, LLVM 15.0.7, DRM 3.52, 6.4.8-t2-jammy)

```
(base) rahul@karmax:~$ uname -a 
Linux karmax 6.4.8-t2-jammy #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Aug  3 18:36:57 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(base) rahul@karmax:~$ sudo lshw -C display 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 40
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=amdgpu latency=0 mode=3072x1920 resolution=3072,1920 visual=truecolor xres=3072 yres=1920
       resources: iomemory:410-40f iomemory:400-3ff irq:87 memory:4100000000-41ffffffff memory:4080000000-40801fffff ioport:3000(size=256) memory:81500000-8157ffff memory:81580000-8159ffff
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:82:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:92000000-92ffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:9000(size=128) memory:93000000-9307ffff
```

1. My challenge is that I installed nvidia-driver-535 the first time I booted in. Then the `nvidia-smi` command responded `No device found`.

- Then I used egpu-switcher(https://github.com/hertg/egpu-switcher) to setup my display configs to use external NVIDIA GPU rather than internal AMD GPU.
- Additionally, I followed a kernel parameter of `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nvidia.NVreg_OpenRmEnableUnsupportedGpus=1 pci=realloc"`, referenced in https://community.frame.work/t/solved-nvidia-drivers-failing-to-load-egpu-on-ubuntu-22-04-1-bios-3-06-beta/25940/17.
- I was able to reboot and my laptop display was showing up but nothing served through the eGPU.

2. Thereafter I tried to downgrade driver version to `nvidia-driver-515` and `nvidia-driver-470`. At this state system did not boot and I was getting multiple errors.

- First error was `[drm:nv_drm_load] *ERROR* Failed to allocate NvKmsKapiDevice` and `[drm:nv_drm_probe_devices] *ERROR* Failed to register device`. However the boot process did not stall and it went through to boot via Nouveau X system.
- However, later on after reinstall attempt of `nvidia-driver-470` and others this error blocked my boot process with error `[FAILED] Failed to start NVIDIA Persistence Daemon` (attached image[Failed to start error NVIIDIA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bH3bV.jpg))
- To resolve this I had to cleanup all nvidia-driver installation in safe-mode boot terminal. Thereafter revert to nouveau drivers and disconnect my eGPU to get to get booted into ubuntu desktop.

I want to be able to install pytorch with Nvidia CUDA drivers for data science work, run `nvidia-smi` to observe the state of my GPU during training without the need of driving an external monitor using eGPU like they do for games.
However, I am unable to get through the drivers installation and test with `nvidia-smi`.

Please let me know if you have any guidance on this issue.

Comment: I would have to be able to duplicate your exact setup, but I am not sure where exactly you got that Kernel from.  That could be what is blocking you from installing the NVIDIA drivers.  The supported HWE Kernel right now in 22.04.3 LTS is 6.2.0-33-generic.

Comment: I used T2Linux guide and prebuilt ISO (https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu/releases/tag/v6.4.8-1) for this installation.
Would you suggest I use 6.2.x versions in their repo as that may relate to the Ubuntu builds.

Comment: It might be something you would file with the creator of that image as an issue to add support to the kernel for the NVIDIA drivers.  They make no mention of it on the page since the MacBookPro does not come with the NVIDIA chipset in it.  It sounds like they created that kernel to bypass the security of the T2 chip.  The nvidia-driver-XXX from the repos uses DKMS to install into the Kernel which requires it to build into the Kernel itself.  The command of `dkms status` should be able to show you if the driver built and installed properly.  Maybe you might need to install `dkms`?

Comment: But, you could try the 6.2.x version if you want.  I wish I had the same hardware as you to test it out and see if I can duplicate your issue.  I will give you a +1 to help visibility here and maybe someone might have had this issue before.

Comment: Thanks @Terrance for your guidance. I did try installing `nvidia-driver-535` and ran the dkms command.

```
$ dkms status 
nvidia/535.104.12, 6.4.8-t2-jammy, x86_64: installed

$ nvidia-smi 
No devices were found
```
I will try the route of v6.2.x to be sure that I am using a supported kernel version.

Comment: Installed  [t2 linux link](https://github.com/t2linux/T2-Ubuntu/releases/tag/v6.2.12-1)
`$ uname -a` 
> Linux karmax 6.2.12-t2-jammy #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Apr 21 04:33:57 UTC 2023 x86_64 GNU/Linux
`$ sudo dkms status` 
> nvidia/535.113.01, 6.2.12-t2-jammy, x86_64: installed
`$ lspci | grep -i vga`
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Navi 14 [Radeon RX 5500/5500M / Pro 5500M] (rev 40)
04:00.1 Non-VGA unclassified device: Apple Inc. T2 Bridge Controller (rev 01)
04:00.2 Non-VGA unclassified device: Apple Inc. T2 Secure Enclave Processor (rev 01)

Comment: I wish so much that I had the same hardware to help you out and duplicate what you are seeing.  But I think I might have found something that looks promising to try.  https://community.frame.work/t/solved-nvidia-drivers-failing-to-load-egpu-on-ubuntu-22-04-1-bios-3-06-beta/25940/10 Post #10 there looks like a good answer (the link should take you right to post #10).

Comment: @Terrence I did try the solution described there but with Ubuntu 22.04 (T2 Linux version) and not Xubuntu 22.10. This is considering the fact that I am installing this on Intel Macbook Pro 16 inch.

Comment: Xubuntu or Ubuntu doesn't matter there.  The underlying is the same on both of them.  But I think one of the biggest things there was installing the `-open` driver.

Comment: I am trying to get an eGPU (Razer X Chroma with 3090) working with an Asus B550 Creator (AMD-based) motherboard.  I can see the internal nVidia GPUs fine, so the problem isn't the nvidia driver, but the Thunderbolt is dead.  "boltclt list" comes up empty, also if I plug in my phone in the USB-C ports.  Old-style USB works.  I've also tested the eGPU with my Intel laptop, and it works fine there.

Perhaps your issue is different, but I think AMD/Thunderbolt is broken, either in hard/firmware, or under Linux.  Maybe there's a BIOS setting that can fix it, but I haven't found it so far.

Comment: BTW, I get a few of these during boot (from dmesg and/or in /var/log/kern.log):
[    5.459842] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0011 address=0xcaeda700 flags=0x0020]
[    7.475916] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0011 address=0xcaeda800 flags=0x0020]
[    9.491893] thunderbolt 0000:06:00.0: AMD-Vi: Event logged [IO_PAGE_FAULT domain=0x0011 address=0xcaeda900 flags=0x0020]

Comment: It looks like my (and possibly yours) problem is that the B550 chipset only supports *either* a PCI card in slot 3 *or* Thunderbolt.  If you have a second GPU (or other PCI card) plugged in, Thunderbolt is disabled.

https://rog-forum.asus.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/75895i6A0AD0E699EDC1F1/image-size/medium?v=v2&px=400